# How to enable verbose flags in my Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How to enable verbose flags in my Gemfile, so that I can track exactly what is happening while building native extensions. Since it is usually taking a very long time to install.

```
gem install libv8
Fetching: libv8-3.11.8.11.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should use:

```
gem install --verbose libv8
```

And through bundle

```
bundle install --verbose
```

Comment: How do I do this when I install it via the bundler. not on the command line.